# Issue with creating a new variable based off of multiple conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column in R based off of existing variables. I have variable A and B, and based off of those values I want to create a variable "C". Variables A and B are part of the "unprocessed_data3" dataframe.

Essentially, I would like volfree to equal 1 if free is 1 and B9_new is 1, and volfree to equal 0 if free is 1 and B9_new is 2, and volfree to be N/A in all other cases. I have the code written in Stata below.

```
> gen volfree=1 if free==1 & B9_new==1

> replace volfree=0 if free==1 & B9_new==2
```

I tried to use the below command.

```
> unprocessed_data3$volfree = with(unprocessed_data3, ifelse(free ==0 , NA,
                               ifelse(B9_new=="1", 1, 0)))
```

I tried using it, but end up with mostly NA and some 0. I expect many NA and some 0, but also a few 1, which did not occur. I know for sure there are some of those conditions.

Below is my code

```
> unprocessed_data <- read.dta('C:/Users/Yuraku/Downloads/04291-0001-Data.dta')
> attach(unprocessed_data)

> unprocessed_data3 <- subset(unprocessed_data, A6 != 5 & A6 !=6)

> free <- unprocessed_data3$B8

> unprocessed_data3$free_2   <- free
> unprocessed_data3$free_new <- unfactor(free)
> unprocessed_data3$B9_new   <- unfactor(unprocessed_data3$B9)
> unprocessed_data3$volfree = with(unprocessed_data3, ifelse(free ==0 , NA,
                               ifelse(B9_new=="1", 1, 0)))
```

Using the summary and head functions, I find that my min, max, and median are all 0. But there should be nearly 50 "1". Furthermore, I also get error of

`>unexpected 'r' after expression`

Instead I did not get this, which is odd.

Comment: Please show a small reproudcible example and expected output.  If you already have missing values (`NA`) in the data set, the `==` returns `NA` for those.  Or else you may need `is.na` to correct for those

Comment: Can you please tell me what reproducible example is？

Comment: Take a look at [mcve]

Comment: I think I made it reproducible?

Comment: It is reproducible once we can run your snippets on our computer, and have the same errors or (subset of) output as you have on your computer. Use the __dput()__ function with the __head()__ of your __unprocessed_data__ dataset.